# Rails: Delete user and user associated data in all associated models

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby ON Rails,
my app has 3 models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :user_hobby
 has_one :user_interest
end

class User_hobby < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User
 end

class User_interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User

 end
```

I want to delete all record and associated data of a specific user from the model and associated data.

i tried:

```
@user = User.joins(:User_details,:User_record).where(user_id:'user_id')
@user.destroy
```

but not working, I want to do without using `dependent: :destroy`
only from SQL

Comment: i want to do without  dependent: :destroy  from sql

Comment: Then you must have to delete all associated record manually.

Comment: "i want to do without dependent: :destroy" - why?

Comment: bcoz i want without primary-key

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Use `dependent` while use any association into model

You can do like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :user_hobby, dependent: :destroy  # destroys the associated user_hobby
 has_one :user_interest, dependent: :destroy  # destroys the associated user_interest
end
```

For more understanding go through this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one)

**dependent**

- Controls what happens to the associated object when its owner is destroyed:
- `:destroy` causes the associated object to also be destroyed
- `:delete` causes the associated object to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not execute)
- `:nullify` causes the foreign key to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not executed.
- `:restrict_with_exception` causes an exception to be raised if there is an associated record
- `:restrict_with_error` causes an error to be added to the owner if there is an associated object

Answer (score 0):

When you setup a model with associations you should also take the time to setup callbacks to handle removing orphaned rows.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_hobby, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user_interest, dependent: :destroy
end

class UserHobby < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class UserInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This will call the `.destroy` method on each associated record:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.destroy
```

Additionally `@user = User.joins(:User_details,:User_record).where(user_id:'user_id')` returns an entire collection of records - not an individual record. The `.where(user_id:'user_id')` is also completely wrong since the condition will apply to the users table and you are using a hardcoded string litteral `'user_id'` which I doubt is in the column.

If you want an individual record use the `.find` or `.find_by` methods.

```
@user = User.includes(:user_details, :user_record).find(params[:id])
@user.user_details.delete_all 
@user.user_record.delete if @user.user_record
```

`.delete_all` or `.destroy_all` should be used if it is a `has_many` association or a collection of records.

But setting up the associations properly is a better idea as models should be in charge of the buisness logic in a MVC application.

Comment: You should also spend a little time learning the naming conventions in Rails (and Ruby) as its really essential. https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming